# Simple array to multidimensional array for file listings

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I'm quite new to programming and I've been trying to get something, that seemed rather simple, done but it's taking me way too long and I do not have the feeling that I'm getting anywhere close...

I'm trying to format an array that looks like this:

```
Array (
    [1] = "index.php"
    [2] = "page.php"
    [3] = "sub/subpage.php"
    [4] = "sub/subpage2.php"
    [5] = "sub/subsub/subsubpage.php"
    [6] = "sub/subsub/subsubpage2.php"
    [7] = "sub2/sub2page.php"
)
```

Into an array that looks like this:

```
Array (
    [/] => Array (
              [0] => "index.php"
              [1] => "page.php"
          )
    [/sub] => Array (
              [0] => "subpage.php"
              [1] => "subpage2.php"
              [/subsub] => Array (
                  [0] => "subsubpage.php"
                  [1] => "subsubpage2.php"
              )
          )
    [/sub2] => Array (
              [0] => "sub2page.php"
          )
)
```

I'm hoping this example shows what I'm trying to do... Which is basically reformatting my original (simple) array into an array that I can use to create some kind of navigation in HTML (using nested ul's)

Thanks in advance!

EDIT:

I've tried this to create the multidimensional array...

```
 $parts = explode('/', trim($page["parent"], "/"));
 while ( !empty($parts) ) {
     $pageList[array_pop($parts)] = $page["filename"];
 }

 // $page = array("filename" => "example.php", "parent" => "sub/sub/")
```

Comment: I'm having problems coming up with a function that does this... I added something I tried to the OP.

Comment: Can you add what the $page object contains?

Comment: I'm sorry, I added that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've prepared an example how to achieve this. The array `$from`

```
$from = array (
    "index.php",
    "page.php",
    "sub/subpage2.php",
    "sub/subsub/subpage2.php",
    "sub2/sub2page.php",
);
```

will be converted to `$to`:

```
$to = array();
foreach($from as $element) {
    $path = explode('/', $element);
    if(count($path) === 1) {
        array_unshift($path, '/');
    }
    $_to = &$to;
    for($i=0; $i<count($path) -1; $i++) {
        if(!array_key_exists($path[$i], $_to)) {
            $_to[$path[$i]]= array();
        }
        $_to = &$_to[$path[$i]];
    }
    $_to []= $path[count($path) -1];
}
var_dump($to);
```

.. what gives you the following array:

```
array(3) {
  '/' =>
  array(2) {
    [0] =>
    string(9) "index.php"
    [1] =>
    string(8) "page.php"
  }
  'sub' =>
  array(2) {
    [0] =>
    string(11) "subpage.php"
    'subsub' =>
    array(1) {
      [0] =>
      string(12) "subpage2.php"
    }
  }
  'sub2' =>
  array(1) {
    [0] =>
    string(12) "sub2page.php"
  }
}
```

Comment: A little less close than Philip. There are 2 problems with this approach. 1) I need `index.php` and `page.php` in one array (with key `/`) and 2) I need `/subsub` inside `/sub`...

Comment: @CasCornelissen If you need subsub in sub, then you'll have just to change `$from`. My code works with that

Comment: Oh wow, it works! Thanks so much... I'm going to try to understand it now, haha.

Comment: Hehe. I can help if you want.

Comment: I think I'm understandig it, you're basically looping over the directories (in the for loop) and add them to the total string using &= and = &, am I right?

Comment: Yes. I'm looping over directories in path ( < count($path) **-1**)  If a directory does not exist in `$to` I create it. The last element is always the filename and will get added to the corresponding directory entry.

Comment: Thanks, that clarified everything!

Comment: Note one last thing. If you don't expect NULL values (unlikely) you can replace `array_key_exists()` by `isset()` which is faster.

Answer (score 1):

You mean something like this - thats just an simple parser

```
$test = array(
    "index.php",
    "page.php",
    "sub/subpage.php",
    "sub/subpage2.php",
    "sub/subsub/subsubpage.php",
    "sub/subsub/subsubpage2.php",
    "sub2/sub2page.php"
);


function buildPathArray($array)
{
    $t = array();

    foreach ($array as $file) {
        $path = "/";
        $name = $file;

        if (preg_match('~^(.*)/([^/]+)$~', $file, $m)) {
            $path = $m[1];
            $name = $m[2];
        }

        $p = &arrayPath($t, $path);

        $p[] = $name;
    }

    return $t;
}

function &arrayPath(&$array, $path = false)
{
    if ($path == false) {
        return $array;
    }
    else
    {
        if (strpos($path, '/') === false) {
            if (!isset($array[$path])) {
                $array[$path] = array();
            }

            return $array[$path];
        }
        else
        {
            preg_match('~([^/]*)/(.*)~', $path, $m);
            if (!isset($array[$m[1]])) {
                $array[$m[1]] = array();
            }

            return arrayPath($array[$m[1]], $m[2]);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This is getting closer but I already got this once (forgot how to though). I need `/subsub` inside `/sub`...

Comment: But this information isn't available in your array structure... you have to replace `subsub/subsubpage.php` with `sub/subsub/subsubpage.php` or this isn't possible

Comment: Oh god, I made a mistake. It has to be like that... I'll fix my OP, could you then look at it again?

Comment: Nevermind, hek2mgl's approach worked. Thanks for your time though!

Comment: Postet an solution as well - especially because of arrayPath which could be usefull for other persons too

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use an array like that you key values need to be in quotes as well. For consider:

```
$array = array(
    '/' => array('index.php', 'page.php'),
    '/sub' => array('blah', 'blah', 'blah'),
    '/sub2' => array('foo', 'bar', 'foobar')
);
```

How you correctly set key values using the `array` keyword is **without** bracket notation. This is **incorrect**

```
$array = array(
    [key] => 'value'
);
```

However, if you want to add something to an array...

```
$array = array();
$array['foo'] = 'bar'; // named key value
$array[] = 'blah'; // automatic numeric key value
$array[] = array('foo', 'bar'); // md array (array inside an array)
```

Hopefully this helps you out some!

Comment: I know how to define arrays, I was using the notation in the example since I want to look them that way when using `print_r`